# d3.js - Tree Layout - How can I flip it?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I'm using this example for a D3.js tree layout.

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

I need to flip it, so the root node is on the right hand side, and the links... etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tree drawing orientation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673335/tree-drawing-orientation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Change the offset of each node to be from the right rather than offset from the left:

  ```
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
  ```

Becomes:

```
    // Normalize for fixed-depth from right.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = w - (d.depth * 180); });
```

- Change the labels to be on the opposite sides

  ```
  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })    
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  ```

Becomes:

```
    nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 10 : -10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "start" : "end"; })    
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

- Make original position of the root node on the right hand side, rather than the left so first transition isn't weird:

  ```
  root = json;
  root.x0 = h / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;
  ```

Becomes:

```
    root = json;
    root.x0 = h / 2;
    root.y0 = w;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ak5tP/1/embedded/result/