# How to make d3 js tree view vertically bottom to up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I want to make a tree view reverse i mean from bottom to up. what changes should i make
here is the js fiddle link

Comment: Have a look at this answer from Bostock: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673335/tree-drawing-orientation

Comment: thanks.
but its very complex.
not helping out for me.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/FMPWuwf7RHJCxc37xRaq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to flip vertically, make y as -y
If you want to flip horizontally, make x as -x